# Can I share a parent table's primary key as a foreign key between two or more child tables?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key, erd

I have a database named tv_shows which is structured as:

```
tv_shows(tv_show_id, tv_show_title, tv_show_desc, network, status)

seasons(season_id, tv_show_id, season_no, season desc)

episodes(episode_id, tv_show_id, season_id, episode_title, episode_desc, episode_ref, air_date)
```

A TV show can have many seasons & episodes
A season can have many episodes
An episode can belong to only one TV show and one season.

What I need to know is how to represent this on an **ERD** given that `tv_shows(tv_show_id)` appears as a **foreign key** in both the seasons and episodes tables.

tv_show's primary key (tv_show_id) is being shared between *two* child tables.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with a table being referenced by multiple other tables.  Your design is OK from that perspective.

You might argue that the `tv_show_id` in `episodes` is superfluous; you could use the `season_id` alone to reference the `seasons` table, and derive the `tv_show_id` from there.  There is also a hidden constraint; you expect the `tv_show_id` stored in `episodes` to be the same as the `tv_show_id` stored in `seasons` for the given `season_id`.  If you don't store the `tv_show_id` in `episodes`, that mismatch cannot occur, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *can* - though it's not clear whether you *should*.

If an episode belongs to exactly one season - i.e. you cannot have an episode without a season - there's no need to include the "show_id" on the episode, as this is implicit in the relationship with the season. It's duplication, and could lead to bogus data - someone could insert an episode with a season that's not associated with the show column.

However, in the real world, not all episodes are associated with a season - there are "one-offs", for instance. If you want to model that, you can include the show_id on the episode table. This leads to slightly awkward logic, though - your queries have to understand that there are two types of relationship between "show" and "episode". It may be better to include an episode for these cases called "no episodes", or whatever, so all the relationships are clear and uniform.

Alternatively, you could have a table called "episode" related to seasons, and a similar table called "one-off".

As you can see, there's no nice way of handling inheritance-style relationships in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on whether you are using **surrogate keys** or **compound keys**.

If your primary keys are all meaningless integers, assigned by an auto_num/identity/sequence, then there is no need to propagate a parent key down to grandchildren.

However, if the primary key of `seasons` were the *combination* of `tv_show_id` and `season_no` then it would make sense for `tv_show_id` to appear in the `episodes` table.

It depends too on how you define your foreign key constraints.  It would be better to define a clear hierarchy, like so:

TV SHOW -|-----< SEASON -|----< EPISODE

This makes it clear that, even if `episodes` has a `tv_show_id` in it, you are supposed to go through `seasons` to get there.  In practice you can always do the join directly, but from a referential integrity standpoint, you don't have to worry about an episode pointing at a show A and a season for show B at the same time.